# Login and Logout of LinkedIn using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I wish to write a program that Logs in and Logs out of LinkedIn in python using Selenium.

I have been able to achieve the Login feature but I cannot really understand how to Log out. I tried to find a solution but best I could reach is

Can someone help me out please?

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Project_Exhibition II/Project_Exhibition_2/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin")
time.sleep(5)

username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
username.send_keys("example@linkedIn.com")
pword = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
pword.send_keys("password\n")

time.sleep(15)

dropdownButton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'global-nav__primary-link')
dropdownButton.click()
signoutButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="/m/logout/"]')
signoutButton.click()

driver.quit()
```

It Logs in fine but then abruptly closes the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logout button just redirects you to "/m/logout".

> '//*[@href="/m/logout/"]'

So you can just run:

```
driver.get("https://linkedin.com/m/logout")
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a little bit trickie...
You need to wait for elements to become clickable and to find the correct locators there.
The following code works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys("my_email@gmail.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("MyPassword")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-litms-control-urn='login-submit']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'global-nav__primary-link')][contains(.,'Me')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='logout']"))).click()
```